# CSS doesn't work on GitHub Pages, only works locally

Tags: html, css, github

I've seen several similar questions to the one I have, but no solutions currently posted have worked for me so far (that I have seen). My css loads and works for me when I test it locally, but when I push to GitHub it doesn't work anymore. My file structure is just an index.html and main.css file in the same folder. My current html tag to link the css is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

I have tried changing the link to "/main.css" and changing the file structure, but so far nothing has changed.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Just Try :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
<!-- Here Head Content-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Here Body Content-->
</body> 
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the css file in a tab, and match the directory.
And if it is correct but also not working(which should not happen.)
Then you can use some of the other solutions toimport CSS, as:

- `<link rel="preload" as="style" href="main.css">`
- `<style src="main.css"></style>`
  **And remember to put the directory correct.**